# c# parallel programming for several methods

Tags: c#

I have a method that looks like this:

```
public void SomeMethodThatLoadsUserData()
{
   Method1();
   Method2();
   Method3();
   .....
   Method12();
}
```

These get executed when the user logs on and each method fetches some data related to the user. I was wondering if making these run in parallel would have any performance benefit because each method ends up calling a query to the same database file. And, if there would be a performance benefit, how would I rewrite this code?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What did you try in terms of making it run in parallel? If you did, did you measure the performance difference?

Comment: It they are all mainly IO-bound, then it is actually possible it would make performance *worse*. If they are mainly CPU-bound, then you might make it a bit faster; it all depends on what the code is doing.

Comment: Try and see `Parallel.Invoke(Method1, Method2, Method3);`

Comment: @MarcGravell: they all end up calling other methods that make calls to the database. I'll look to compare performance. Will the performance gain/loss that I'll measure on my laptop be similar when I'll port to azure?

Comment: @L.B: You should create an answer for your suggestion.

Comment: @frenchie no in fact, it doesn't answer anything.

Comment: @L.B: With my code, after running the methods about 10 times in a row, I got the execution to average about 350ms. With your suggestion, the same experiment runs the queries in less than 300ms. Why are you skeptical?

Comment: @MarcGravell: it improved performance: from about 350ms to about 220ms on average. Is that a definite good thing or could it still reverse when I'll deploy to azure?

Comment: @frenchie re azure. Good question, and only one way to find the answer.

Comment: @MarcGravell: ok, thanks; I'll remeasure on azure when I get to that point.

Comment: @frenchie because I didn't say anything about performance, I just said try and see. How to do it was not your question.

Comment: @L.B: ok, well anyway, you gave me the answer, thanks a lot!!

Comment: @MarcGravell: quick question, when you're operating StackExchange, what is the range in ms that it takes for a page's database query to run?

Comment: @frenchie firstly "query" (singular) is entirely misleading; different pages require different numbers of queries, and take different times. Don't have the "average" on me (and too lazy to go look it), however, **this** very page here that I'm commenting on - took 34.5ms server-side, from start-to-end of the MVC pipe

Comment: ok thanks, this gives me a pretty good idea. In my case, I'm building a single-page app and I need to fetch all sorts of data in the initial load. Thank Marc for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code demonstrates a parallel test using a list of Thread and Stopwatch objects. I think this is pretty good method to test with because it guarantees a parallel execution attempt (unlike Parallel.Invoke) and it's easier to set up than using the ThreadPool IMO.

```
public static void SomeMethodThatLoadsUserData()
{
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();

    List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread> {new Thread(Method1), new Thread(Method2)};

    foreach (Thread thread in threads)
    {
        thread.Start();
    }

    foreach (Thread thread in threads)
    {
        thread.Join();
    }

    s.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Total: {0} ms", s.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void Method1()
{
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();
    // do work
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    s.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Method 1: {0} ms", s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

private static void Method2()
{
    Stopwatch s = new Stopwatch();
    s.Start();
    // do work
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    s.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Method 2: {0} ms", s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

Output:

```
Method 1: 999 ms
Method 2: 999 ms
Total: 1051 ms
```

Any time saving will show up when (hopefully) `Total` is less than the sum of each method.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this is the fastest or the best way of doing it but you could spin each method off to a new thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => Method1());
t.Start();
```